# Visual studio cannot connect to MS SQL SERVER 2000

Tags: sql, vb.net

HI all,

Im using windows vista home premuim, and I've install Visual studio 2008 and MS SQL 2000 in my laptop,

My problem was i cannot establish data connection, an error said , LOGIN failed for REJ(SQL SERVER). Im using windows authentication in connecting my visual studio to SQL

Comment: Can you post the connection string you're attempting to use to connect to the local SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

SQLServer uses a 2 step authentication: 
1) connect to the service
2) connect to the initial catalog

So first you have to make sure that your windows user can connect to the service, by checking whether your windows user is part of the users list of the service itself. Then you have to make sure that that user is indeed allowed to access the catalog you specified as the initial catalog (or if you connect to the catalog from a server browser for example, the catalog you try to access to the UI).

sqlserver 2008 by default doesn't allow outside connections, so if you're connecting to the service using 'machinename' (the name of your computer), try '(local)'